# What are the differences between autocomplete and company mode?

Tags: completion, company-mode, auto-complete-mode

There seem to be two major autocompletion extensions for emacs: autocomplete and company mode. What are some of the practical differences between the two and when would I want to use one over the other? Also, are they compatible with each other?

Comment: What do you mean by _“Also, are they compatible with each other?”_? Are you asking if they can be used at the same time? Or if the sources of one can be used by the other?

Comment: If they can use the same sources

Comment: https://github.com/company-mode/company-mode/issues/68 (not much more to add).

Answer (score 37, accepted):

I've used autocomplete-mode for a good a few years and switched to company-mode a couple of months ago.

In basic usage there's not much of a difference. Like someone else posted [this link](https://github.com/company-mode/company-mode/issues/68) has a good summary of the differences.

I found company-mode to be easier to configure and to let it do what I want it to. With autocomplete-mode I ran into issues now and then of something not working the way I wanted it to and then something else falling over when tweaking it. In usage, I rarely feel company-mode is in the way when using Emacs while autocomplete-mode did get in the way now and then.

Also, for developers it is easy to add support for their packages to company-mode, see: [EmacsWiki:CompanyMode:Backends](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/CompanyMode#toc1).

They are not compatible with each other. For now, there's more packages that support autocomplete-mode but that is changing fast.

tl;dr. They pretty much do the same thing. Start with company-mode and try autocomplete-mode if you miss anything from the former.

Answer (score 41):

They're pretty much equivalent, but `company-mode` has a better thought-out API for plugin developers. It's also much more actively maintained. But there are two key differences which may or may not matter to you:

Firstly, `company-mode` now targets Emacs 24, so if you're stuck with Emacs 23 then you're out of luck. `auto-complete` still works with Emacs 23.

Secondly, `auto-complete` has a "popup docs" mechanism which displays a tool-tip-like yellow overlay in the current buffer showing info about the symbol at point. IIRC, `company-mode` can pull in the same info, but it does it in a separate window right now.

There's [an issue](https://github.com/company-mode/company-mode/issues/138) filed for that, and it seems likely that `company-mode` will gain popup doc support, perhaps via an add-on package. Historically, such popup windows have been somewhat buggy, so it might be worth getting used to `company`'s separate-window approach.

If you're starting afresh now, and you have Emacs 24, `company-mode` is the way to go.

Comment: As an aside, I think the name is unfortunate. I had assumed that company-mode had something to do with managing multi-user projects (as in a project run by a company). I would have found it earlier if it had an obvious name like autocomplete does!

Comment: Yes, `comp-any` would have been clearer than `company`.